# how do I save only certain fields of a model in django

Tags: python, django

I have django server that receives a user uploaded file, then stores the metadata locally for further retrieving but sends the file to another server. So I don't want the file be stored locally. Here is my initial model:

```
class MainFile(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    docfile = models.FileField(verbose_name= 'Enter you file', null=True)
    file_id = models.TextField(max_length=38, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return MainFile.file_id

class MainFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MainFile
        fields = ['docfile']
```

I used instance.save('owner', 'file_id'), I got the error: "Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key" so I changed my model to following:

```
class MainFile(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
docfile = models.FileField(verbose_name= 'Enter you file', null=True)
file_id = models.TextField(max_length=38, primary_key=True, default=1)
```

after altering my models I get the error: "The following fields do not exist in this model or are m2m fields: file_id"

and here's my view:

```
@login_required
def StoreSegments(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MainFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file_id = uuid.uuid4()
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.owner = request.user
            instance.file_id = file_id
            instance.save(update_fields=['file_id', 'owner'])
            f = request.FILES['docfile']
            urls = 'http://192.168.43.6:8000/StoreSegments'
            r=requests.post(urls, files= {'segment': f}, data={'segmentID':file_id})
            form.save()
            context = {'form': form, 'message': r.status_code}
            return render(request, "StoreSegments.html", context)
    form = MainFileForm()
    return render(request, 'StoreSegments.html', context={'message': 'request.method =="get" detected',
                                             'form': form})
```

So, how can I can only save the metadata and post the file away?

Comment: Would it not be better to actually fix the errors? Having a foreign key thats a `TextField` isn't a very good idea anyway, especially when the name of that `TextField` suggests that it would make more sense as an `IntegerField`

Comment: Did you migrate the changes you made in the models?

Comment: @Sayse I am filling the textfield with uuid4 in the view; I'm going to change it to UUIDField see how it works.

Comment: @maSnun Yes I performed the migrations

Comment: @Sayse I changed the textfield to uuidfield, same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to force a primary key, you just need to attach the user object. As you do not want to save the file locally, you don't need to have it as part of your model.

You do want the user to upload the file though, so you do need it as part of your form.

The first step would be to remove the file field from your model, and add a file upload field to your *form*.

I would also recommend adding some meta information on the status of the file as processed by your third party, but you can add this later as an enhancement.

Using your original model, you would just need a normal form with one field:

```
class MainFile(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file_id = models.TextField(max_length=38, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return MainFile.file_id

class MainFileForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField()
```

Here is how you should update the view:

```
from django.contrib import messages

@login_required
def StoreSegments(request):
    form = MainFileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        file_id = uuid.uuid4()
        MainFile.objects.create(owner=request.owner, file_id=file_id)
        f = request.FILES['docfile']
        urls = 'http://192.168.43.6:8000/StoreSegments'
        r=requests.post(urls, files= {'segment': f}, data={'segmentID':file_id})
        messages.info(request, r.status_code)
        return redirect("/thank-you") # You should always redirect after POST
    return render(request,
                  'StoreSegments.html',
                   context={'message': 'request.method =="get" detected',
                            'form': form})
```

You should always redirect after a successful POST request (see [this article on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) for the details).

Have a look at the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-a-message) to display the resulting message on your thank-you page.

Comment: Thank you, But instance.save() is going to save the file locally right? I don't want that to happen that's my main goal here.